# Pull out unique values from data frame and make on column using r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

How do I pull out unique values from each column in a data frame (both numeric and strings) and make into one column?

```
a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a")
b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3)
df <- cbind(a, b)
```

The preferred output would be:

```
 variable     Level
 a            a
 a            b
 a            c
 a            d
 b            1
 b            2
 b            3
 b            4
```

The sample data above is simple but the intent is to be able to use the answer for multiple data frame with different column names and data in them.  Thank you.

Comment: Should `df` be a data.frame like `data.frame(a, b)`? If so, see my answer below, it can be a one-liner using `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Quick + scalable

Tidyr's `gather` and dplyr's `distinct` gives you a quick way to get that structure. (I left the package calls in the functions so you can remember which one is from which package, which I always forget.)

```
library(tidyverse)
a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a")
b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3)
data.frame(a,b) %>% tidyr::gather() %>% dplyr::distinct()

  key value
1   a     a
2   a     b
3   a     c
4   a     d
5   b     1
6   b     2
7   b     3
8   b     4
```

Comment: This is perfect. Worked like a charm! Thank you @Jesse Tweedle

Answer (score 2):

We place it in a `list`, get the `unique` elements, set the names with `letters` and then `stack` to data.frame

```
d1 <- stack(setNames(lapply(list(a, b), unique), letters[1:2]))[2:1]
colnames(d1) <- c('variable', 'Level')
```

Comment: @catastrophic-failure  Thanks, fixed the text part.

Answer (score 1):

`df` data.frame creation:

```
a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a")
b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3)
df <- cbind(a, b)
```

Columns name extraction

```
names<-colnames(df)
```

Data Extration

```
variable<-NULL
Level<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(names))
{
  variable<-c(variable,rep(names[i],length(unique(df[,i]))))
  Level<-c(Level,unique(df[,i]))
}
```

Your generic output

```
db<-cbind(variable,Level)
db
     variable Level
[1,] "a"      "a"  
[2,] "a"      "b"  
[3,] "a"      "c"  
[4,] "a"      "d"  
[5,] "b"      "1"  
[6,] "b"      "2"  
[7,] "b"      "3"  
[8,] "b"      "4"
```

Comment: Hi @Terru_theTerror.  How can I scale that though.  This totally works for the sample data, but the actual data frame will have different column names in it.  My apologies as I should have stated that above.

Comment: Changed code in a "generic" application of the problem working on several columns with unknown column names